# How to install scripts to sbin with python's distutils?

Tags: python, installation, distutils

Commonly on most unix systems there is a distinction between `$PREFIX/bin` and `$PREFIX/sbin`. When installing a piece of software the administrator decides about what `$PREFIX` is, but the author decides which programs are suitable for regular users and which are not. With Python's `distutils` a set of `scripts` can be defined and they are installed to `$PREFIX/bin`. So how to install a script to the corresponding sbin directory?

Note that in this case solutions targeting only Linux are welcome, because other parts of the software in question depend on iptables.

Comment: Working with `distutils` was so frustrating, that I decided to use a Makefile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify where files should be installed in the data_files parameter. It should work putting '/sbin' in the directory specification:

```
setup(...,
      data_files=[('/sbin', ['rootfill']),
                  ('/etc/init.d', ['init-script'])]
     )
```

Comment: The issue with using data_files instead of scripts is that the shebang won’t be changed to use the path to the Python used to run setup.py.  This can be viewed as good or bad.

Answer (score 1):

For distutils, we are working on support to install scripts into prefix/sbin.

Comment: Oh I think I was talking about distutils2 in my reply.  The project is now abandoned.  I don’t know if the current efforts around packaging tools take sbin into account.